# How to iterate over selected rows in pandas

Tags: pandas

I need to iterate some selected rows in a pandas dataframe. I tried 'for index, row in df.iterrows()' to iterate over all rows. How can I select the rows I want to iterate? say row 50-100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by that:

```
for index, row in df.iloc[50:100].iterrows()
```